# How to keep the header at fixed position even while page is scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a header which remains fixed at top but what happens is when i scroll down the page the header moves along with it while maintaining its position.
**My requirement is that the header shouldn't move with the page as we scroll down.**

```
JS FIDDLE:https://jsfiddle.net/qa5d1ry0/
```

***Note***: Its just a dummy code of my layout and i have added random text in order to get the code working

***Note***: I have tried  using **position:absolute** for header but the problem is that header don't get displayed as we scroll

Comment: Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/qa5d1ry0/3/ !

Comment: yes some what like that but i still want the header to be displayed even while page is being scrolled

Answer (score 2):

Try to give `position: fixed;` to the header and remove the relative position from container.

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `top:0px;` after your `position:fixed;` for the header/heading div.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed for me. Try `position: fixed`. What browser are you using?